# Image Border Removal - Magento Category Pages

Tags: magento

I have been trying to enhance my category pages with static blocks and images. I'd like to place an image in Catalog - Categories - Manage Categories - General Information - Image, but I don't want a border to appear once I've uploaded the image. How do I go about removing the border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please post a snapshot the border you are mentioning above? Also if it is the css border, you can use css property {border : none} for the image container.

Comment: Can't figure out how to post a snapshot, but the url is: www.redsgear.com/fishing.html. You'll see the border around the "Free Ground Shipping" image.

Comment: What you need to so is, go to chrome, right click on the image and click on inspect element. You will see the html. Actually the <p> tag ( with class="category-image")which is the parent of this <img> tag has border given in css as "border: 1px solid #cccccc;" You need to change it to "border:none;" inside your styles.css file. This will solve your problem. :)

Comment: I corrected the .css file and uploaded it to my FTP, but no changes have occurred on the frontend. I also flushed cache. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Hey, I just checked your website again, the border is gone, maybe it was your browser cache. Try in incognito window or in some other browser. :)